# How do I verify that this function is a string in PHPUnit?

Tags: php, phpunit

Here's the code for my original PHP code:

```
public function outputText() {   
    $i = 1;   
    foreach($this->sorted_data as $this->data) {   
        echo "$i. ".$this->data[0]."<br/>";   
        $i++;  
    }  
}
```

And here's the code for the PHPUnit:

```
public function testVerify() {
    $yn = new SortThisData();
    $yn->readFile("input.txt");
    $output = $yn->outputText();
    $this->assertTrue(is_string($output));

    //if(!is_string($yn->get()))
    //    return false;
    //$this->assertNotEmpty($yn->get());
    }
```

The class is called SortThisData in the original PHP file.
When I used gettype(), it said it was null. I'm trying to verify that it is a string so it can pass in PHPUnit. Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `assertInternalType()`.

**Update:** I didn't realize you were echoing the output. You will probably need to use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) to capture the text.

```
public function testVerify() {
    $yn = new SortThisData();
    $yn->readFile("input.txt");

    // start output buffering and capture the output
    ob_start();
    $yn->outputText();
    $output = ob_get_clean();

    $this->assertInternalType('string', $output);
}
```

Comment: It says :      
There was 1 failure:

1) SortThisDataTest::testVerify
Failed asserting that null is of type "string".

Comment: Thanks it worked, but can you explain what ob_start(); and ob_get_clean(); and buffer does? I'm new to programming and PHP/PHPUnit, and I don't really get the manual from PHP.

Comment: @RaymondYan when you call `echo` in PHP it will display the text immediately. With output buffering you can grab the text and store it in a variable, and it won't be displayed. It kind of replicates using a return statement in a function. I wouldn't suggest designing your scripts to take advantage of output buffering all the time. But in this particular case I think it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

No disagreement with Baylor's answer. To answer the question, as asked, what you had was also good enough:

```
$this->assertTrue(is_string($output));
```

Or you could have done:

```
$this->assertEquals('string',gettype($output));
```

(The advantage of the latter is, when it fails, it will also tell you the type of `$output`; `assertTrue` will only tell you that something failed.)

`assertInternalType()` does exactly that, but was only introduced in PHPUnit 3.5, and you will still find PHPUnit 3.4 in use on some machines.

Comment: It _did_ work; it said $output was null ;-) The fact that `$output` was null was the bug (as Baylor already explained). Your outputText() function returns null (implicitly - you have no return statement in there). So, either use output buffering, or refactor your outputText() to create and return a string.